# Add the XFN 'me' link to RSS feeds

Tags: feature-request, feed

It'd be nice if we could associate our SO accounts so that new questions that we ask could show up in Google Buzz.

According to the [Google Buzz documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/documentation/#connect), all you need to do is add something like this to the feed:

```
<link rel="me" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/profiles/your.username"/>
```

**Edit**: It seems there is currently a "me" link on the website tag in the profile page, which can be picked up.

In addition, you can make chains in the social graph: If you link to your website from Stack Overflow, and then link to your Google profile from your website, this will allow Buzz to pickup Stack Overflow as a content source. (I think you have to include all stages of the chain as links on your profile though.)

Comment: So, you are basically suggesting that SO adds a field where you can specify the location of your profile(s) (Google or otherwise), right?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but I wasn't sure if the SO team would be open to adding more configuration options to the UI. For people using Google for OpenID, there are no extra UI controls needed.

Comment: I answered that here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39041/enable-stackoverflow-as-connected-site-to-google-buzz/39065#39065

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can start by making sure you're using your Google Profile as your OpenID, which we already fully endorse and support:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/